FastAPI real time streaming response
I have created a testmain.py and that has the following code:
from starlette.responses import StreamingResponse
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI
import json

app = FastAPI()

async def generator():
    for i in range(10):
        yield json.dumps({"eid":i,"data":f"{i+1}data chunk","is_final_event":i ==9}) + '\n'
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

@app.get("/")

def root():
    return StreamingResponse(generator(),media_type="application/x-ndjson")

When I run the swagger to test the response from http://127.0.0.1:8000/, I get the final response in one-GO and not in real-time (streaming-mode) as and when the yield is executed. It is all responded at once after completion of execution in 10 seconds. How to change this so that it gets responded in real-time. I tried with postman to check the request url but same behavior. It doesn't give streaming response as the execution happens. Please advise

Does this answer your question?

With regard to Swagger, you might find this answer and this answer helpful. In short, Swagger UI uses a JavaScript fetch() request behind the scenes; hence the behaviour you encountered.
